# ITunes app URl in SMS content

Tags: iphone

In my iPhone application, the user can send the itunes url of the application to other users.

Is there any way to include the URL in the application because as far as I know, the URL is available only after the application goes live.

May be dumb a question. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can always redirect the user to a specially crafted URL: http://itunes.com/app/*app-name-here*.

For example, if I wanted to redirect the user to the store for the app "Tumbledrop", I would redirect to http://itunes.com/app/Tumbledrop.

Alternatively, if this wont work, you can always point the user to a regular HTML page on a web server and put redirect (possibly through JavaScript) on it once you know the full URL in the iTunes app store, although this approach might be slightly slower as it would involve opening Safari first.