# Is there a global iTunes URL for use inside an email, SMS, or other "share this app" msg?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, app-store, itunes

Copying the iTunes link for an app includes my home country, but sharing this same link with people in Hong Kong fails to surface the app.

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408509/itunes-app-url-in-sms-content) shows how to craft one using the app name, but what if we want to reference the app ID and not the app name (since we may change the name based on a user survey)?

What's the right iTunes app URL for global sharing purposes? In other words, the same URL should lead to the app regardless of the user's country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=516500375&mt=8
```

Just replace id with your app id and you are done.

Hope this helps you...

Answer (score 0):

iTunes doesn't offer any links that are truly global.

You can use third party services that are free like [GeoRiot](http://georiot.com) or [SmartURL](http://smarturl.it) that are built specifically to solve this problem for the iTunes store.

Simply copy/paste any iTunes link into the form on the home page and each of the services return a link that can be used world-wide.